# top alignment of a figure in beamer columns not working

Tags: beamer, floats, vertical-alignment, alignment

I have the problem that the figure is differently placed regarding the top space in dependance on whether I put it into a column or not.

What I try to achive is that the figure starts at the same heights in a column as without it.

So basically I thing the T option for columns does not do the job here but I do not know why...

Here is a minimal example (replace the figure with an existing one):

```
\documentclass[final,t]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  begin{columns}[T,onlytextwidth]
    \centering
    \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
       \begin{figure}
          \includegraphics[scale=1]{image.pdf}
          \caption{aha}
       \end{figure}
    \end{column}
  \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
  test
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{image.pdf}
       \caption{aha}
    \end{figure}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The difference in height is caused by the `figure` environment which adds some vertical space around the figure. As a workaround you could use the `\captionof` command from the `caption` package instead.

```
\documentclass[final,t]{beamer}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}[T,onlytextwidth]
%    \centering
    \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
%       \begin{figure}
                    \centering
          \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-duck}
          \captionof{figure}{heading}
%          \caption{aha}
%       \end{figure}
    \end{column}
  \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
  test
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-duck}
       \caption{aha}
    \end{figure}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is a nice workaround. However, I still do not undersand how column envirnment affects the space the figure environment is adding. Because the top space is different with and without columns while it is a figure environment all the time...

Comment: I am **not** trying to have exactly the same height as the text on the other side but the same space from the top for figures placed in columns or directly in the frame.

Comment: @Satas If the figure is at the top of the page, the space above the figure gets skipped, this does not happen inside columns.

Comment: And there is no option to skip it inside columns as well?

Comment: @Satas Why? The `figure` environment doesn't do much more than centring the image. Leaving it out is the simplest solution.

Comment: Because I use snippets for figure insertion, often copy figures from one place to another (also from non-beamer) and do not want to paste and remove the evironments all the time.

So, yes, it is not needed but it is convinient to not insert figures in different ways.

Comment: And what about the space between the figure and the caption, will it be exacly the same when using `\captionof`?